# How would this variable look like in the var?

Tags: javascript

```
    knownPremiums = {}       
    knownPremiums[userId] = { expiration: data.data.expiration ? new Date(data.data.expiration).getTime() : null };
```

How would this look like in knownPremiums?
Let's say the userId = 1
would it look like "1" : "expiration" : 10-0-2019 or something?
I really need this for something :/

Comment: I would suggest using the [console of a browser](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) or the [node REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) to find out. Just enter your code then the variable and you can see it's value

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question correctly - yes object keys are always of type `String` or otherwise coerced to type `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Google is a magic helpful tool. Try it! 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```
knownPremiums = {
    1: {
        // if data.data.expiration exists then return 
        // new Date(data.data.expiration).getTime()
        // number of miliseconds since that date.
        // if not, return null.
        expiration: data.data.expiration ? new Date(data.data.expiration).getTime() : null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow has this really cool javascript snippet function.
So we can just enter the code, and press the "Run code snippet" button to see the result.

**With the expiration date undefined**

> knownPremiums={
>     "1": {
>       "expiration": null
>     }
>   }

**With the expiration date defined:**

> knownPremiums= {
>     "1": {
>       "expiration": 1519084800000
>     }
>   }

```js
var userId=1;
var data={  data:{}  };
var knownPremiums = {}       

knownPremiums[userId] = { expiration: data.data.expiration ? new Date(data.data.expiration).getTime() : null };
console.log("With the expiration date undefined", knownPremiums);

data.data.expiration="2018-02-20";
knownPremiums[userId] = { expiration: data.data.expiration ? new Date(data.data.expiration).getTime() : null };
console.log("With the expiration date defined", knownPremiums);
```